# How to create an html page with an external JS file that validates this format AAA.111#2222_aa-1234

Tags: javascript, validation, external

This is my html page. I'm trying to validate this format AAA.111#2222_aa-1234. I'm not sure what's stopping the html file from accessing the JS file. OR if my regular expression in the JS file is even correct.

```
    <html lang = "en">
    <head>
        <title>random</title>
    </head>
    
    <body>
         <form>
<p>Please enter course information</p>
  <input type="text" name="userInput" id="userInput" maxlength="15">
  <input type="button" value="validate" onclick="validationFunction()">
</form>

    </body>
    </html>
```

This is my external JS file.

```
function validationFunction(input) {
    var userCourse = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
    var myRegularExpression = /[a-z]{3}(.\d{3})(#\d{4})(_[a-z]{2})(-\d{4})/gi;
    return (myRegularExpression.test(input));
}

if (validationFunction(userInput)){
text = "valid";
} else {
    text = "invalid";
}
document.getElementById("validationResults").innerHTML = text;
```

Comment: I think that a service like https://regex101.com/ will help you determine if your regex is correct

Comment: Please always use the preview window when editing questions.

Answer (score 0):

What a mess! Seems like you have all the stuff that you've learnt mixed in your mind :). Don't let this turn you down, we've all been there someday.

Well dude, let's get into your code a bit by a bit.

First of all, you need to learn something about forms; forms work when you submit and set an action with a serverside language. What actually happens when you submit a form with a `GET` method, it gets all the parameters that the user set in your form and calls a serverside file which you specify in the `action` of that form. The request in a `GET` case will be added to the link as query string. Let's see an example. Suppose that you set the action of the form to `action="yourServersideFile.php`, so this is the file that will process the request. then in your form there are two inputs with names: `name` and `number` in their tags. The request when you submit the form will be something like this: https://yourapp.com/yourServersideFile.php?name=yourname&number=yourNumber.

After submitting, the file `yourServersideFile.php` will process the data that has been passed to it in the query string, make the calculations, and **AFTER THAT** `yourServersideFile.php` will send the response either at the same url or will pass it to another response page that will display the results.

If you thought about that process, your page has been distroyed after clicking the submit button and sent the data to a file on the server, then the caclculations ran on the server, then the server sent you a new page.

Now let's see the first mistake in your code, you used clientside javascript to process a form. When you use javascript, all what you've built will be distroyed with the page after you submit the form except the information you might've sabed in the localStorage. So, you will never ever in the real life see a form with `action="somefile.js"` with the js extension unless if your backend in in Node.Js, and in this case that will even be a bad way to use Node.js. Better for you to setup an endpoint in less than a minute with Express and use AJAX to finsih all your needs without reloading the page.

Well, now we realize that we need to change the form and button to normal input and link.

Next, you have defined a function, but it will never fire as you have not set any event to trigger the function nor have you called it.

Javascript is basically an event driven language; when an even happens (typing, click, moving mouse, etc...) that triggers an event, this event triggers some functions. So, to get our function into action we need to set an event to let Javascript know that it should run this function now. So in the javascript I've added an event listener to detect a click on our link (which replaces that button).

After that you'll see the comments in the JS code attached.

So to have your code running here are the HTML and js files that your files need to run like them:

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>random</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <label for="userCourse">Please enter your course information:</label>
    <input type="text" id="userCourse" name="userCourse">
    <a href="#" id="my-button">New Validate</a>

    <p id="validationResults"></p>
  </div>

  <script src="validation.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

and your js code should be like this:

```
//capture the button
document.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  if (event.target.id === 'my-button') { //that detects a click on the button
    const input = document.getElementById('userCourse').value //this stores the text from the input in a variable called input

    const myRegularExpression = /[a-z]{3}(.\d{3})(#\d{4})(_[a-z]{2})(-\d{4})/gi

    // now you test the value of the input
    if (input) {
      var result = myRegularExpression.test(input) //store the test results

      // then display it in the p tag
      document.getElementById('validationResults').innerHTML = result? "valid" : "invalid"
    }

    console.log(typeof(myRegularExpression))

    event.preventDefault()
  }
})
```

I wish that was helpful to let you understand how it works :).

Comment: This helped me understand somewhat better. I changed the form around some and got rid of the action. My button still seems to not be working. I really appreciate the breakdown you did its awesome. Thanks.

Comment: I updated the original with the new form I made. My button still isnt doing anything. Im sorry if i still have mistakes but I just started learning javascript and I truly appreciate your help.

Comment: Don't worry dear Fabian, we've all got help here all the time, and now I'm just rolling the ball :).

Comment: The problem with the button input is that it makes the page reloads. This is why I've replaced it with an Anchor tag `<a>`. The Anchor tag can be much easier to handle with Javascript. You can also style it as a button, see https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/buttons/, you can use this style to your anchor tag to look like a button with css.
This is also why I have put this line in my javascript file `event.preventDefault()`. What `preventDefault()` does is that it blocks the event target which is the Anchor tag in our case from triggering the default action.

Comment: Try making the link target something like google.com. without prevent default all the js will be done then the link will go to google. But, with using prevent default, that stops the link from going to the target.