# Why is my button not activating my validation function

Tags: javascript, validation

I have an html page that access an external javascript file to validate the users input. My button doesnt seem to be doing anything and I dont understand why.

```
<html lang = "en">
<head>
    <title>random</title>
</head>

<body>

     <form>
<p>Please enter course information</p>
  <input type="text" name="userInput" id="userInput" maxlength="15">
  <input type="button" value="validate" onclick="validationFunction()">
```

```
<p id = "validationResults"></p> 


</body>
</html>
```

//My external JS file that is supposed to validate the pattern WEB.110#4101_sp-2017

```
function validationFunction(input) {
    var myRegularExpression = /([a-z]{3})(\W\d{3})(\W\d{4})(\W[a-z]{2})(\W\d{4})/gi;
    return (myRegularExpression.test(input));
}

if (validationFunction(userInput)){
text = "valid";
} else {
    text = "invalid";
}
document.getElementById("validationResults").innerHTML = text;
```

Comment: If you see your page reloading, than clearly the form is submitted and it's too late for validation.

Comment: Someone took the time to answer the [same question you posted an hour ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62374411/need-help-creating-an-html-page-with-an-external-js-file-that-validates-this-for). Why would you not reply to that answer, and just post your question again? If the answer satisfies your needs, accept it. If it does not, comment it, and discuss. Don't run away

Comment: inside the else block use Event.preventDefault() . Google it on MDN if you don't know it does.

Comment: Im not running im currently working and changing the code. This one is has a different form from the last one i posted. I took what the last guy said and made some changes.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp

Check this function 
may be this is what you looking for

Answer (score 0):

The below code works for what you want to achieve. Issues I noticed with your code:

- Your form element had no closing tag
- Rather than adding an onclick to a button within a form, you are better submitting the whole form, and grabbing the event object from an onsubmit event
- You need to preventDefault on the event which stops the page refreshing
- Your maxLength was set to 15 but your target expression is 20 characters
- Your RegEx works, but could be cleaner

  ```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html>
      <head>
          <title>random</title>
          <script src="./script.js" defer></script>
      </head>
      <body>
      <form id="form">
        <p>Please enter course information</p>
        <input type="text" name="userInput" id="userInput" maxlength="20"/>
        <input type="submit"></input> 
      </form>
      <p id="validationResults"></p>
      </body>
      </html>
  ```

  ---

  ```
  const form = document.getElementById("form");
  const paragraph = document.getElementById("validationResults");

  form.addEventListener('submit', validationFunction);


  function validationFunction(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      const userInput = event.target.querySelector("#userInput").value;
      const regEx = /([a-z]{3}(.\d{3})(#\d{4})(_[a-z]{2})(-\d{4}))/gi;
      const isValid = regEx.test(userInput);
      if (isValid) {
          paragraph.innerHTML = "Valid";
      } else {
          paragraph.innerHTML = "Invalid";
      }
  };
  ```